# Select different columns from multiple tables based on common columns

Tags: sql

How would i combine the following tables to this result?

The result should be one row for very idUnit that has the latest date combined with Table2 on matching IDs for that row.

I have managed to combine the tables but not based on the latest date.

Example data:

```
Table1
id    idUnit    Date                  extra
1     1         2017-01-23 01:00:00   a
2     1         2017-01-23 02:00:00   b
3     2         2017-01-23 01:00:00   c
4     2         2017-01-23 02:00:00   d


Table2
id    date                   extra2
1     2017-01-23 01:00:00    w
2     2017-01-23 02:00:00    x
3     2017-01-23 01:00:00    y
4     2017-01-23 02:00:00    z


Result
id    idUnit    Date                  extra    extra2
2     1         2017-01-23 02:00:00   b        x
4     2         2017-01-23 02:00:00   d        z
```

Comment: You should use explicit join syntax, it's ANSI standard since 92! You can use Google for how to incorporate the max date; this type of question has been asked many many many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use modern JOIN syntax rather than comma separated tables with WHERE.

So your SQL becomes

```
select t1.id, t1.idUnit, MAX(t1.date), t1.?, t2.? from table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.date
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.idUnit, t1.?, t2.?
```

Note that you have to include in the GROUP BY all the other fields that you want in the SELECT (where I have t1.? and t2.? as place holders)

EDIT

Having seen the sample data, try the following.  If you are using SQL Server you can copy the whole thing and paste into a query window.  The same sort of sub-query approach as used below, can be done in any db.

```
declare @table1 table
(
id int,
idUnit int,
tDate datetime,
extraCol varchar(10)
)
declare @table2 table
(
id int,
tDate datetime,
extraCol varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(1, 1, '2017-01-23 01:00:00', 'a')
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(2, 1, '2017-01-23 02:00:00', 'b')
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(3, 2, '2017-01-23 01:00:00', 'c')
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES(4, 2, '2017-01-23 02:00:00', 'd')

INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES(1, '2017-01-23 01:00:00', 'w')
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES(2, '2017-01-23 02:00:00', 'x')
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES(3, '2017-01-23 01:00:00', 'y')
INSERT INTO @table2 VALUES(4, '2017-01-23 02:00:00', 'z')

SELECT t1.id, t1.idUnit, t1.tDate, t1.extraCol, t2.extraCol FROM @table1 t1
INNER JOIN @table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.tDate = t2.tDate
INNER JOIN
(SELECT idUnit,  MAX(tDate) as maxDate FROM @table1 
GROUP By idUnit) m
ON t1.idUnit = m.idUnit and t1.tDate = m.maxDate
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: This did not have the expected result unfortunately.

The max(Date) was not the max date for each idUnit, and it was more than 1 row for each idUnit, the combination of id and date should be unique. I think i might have explained poorly, but after filtering for max(date) i expectedonly 1 row for each idUnit (the latest one) left in table 1 which is joined with table 2

Comment: So can you please give us some sample data and expected outcome?  That would make life much easier.

Comment: Updated the original question

Comment: Sorry was out on my bike!  Final question - which db are you using.  The syntax is different for each

Comment: I have edited my answer giving sql server syntax, but it should be easy to change for other db, if the exact same does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this. in here those two tables are connected using Inner join.

```
 SELECT MAX(t1.date) FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table2.id = table1.id and table1.date= table2.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your question is mostly on how to get the Max(id) per idUnit - after that the Join is simply according to the ID column (simple inner join)
If your DB supports it the simplest solution is using window functions (Partition over the idUnit order by date)

If your DB doesn't support it yet (like MySQL 5.7) then you could use some nested query to find the rows with the max date for each idUnit.
(note it's usually much slower...)

Regards,
Jony